# Automatically render special characters used for displaying progress bars etc. in program output saved in a file

Tags: shell, special-characters

I have run a program in the shell and redirected the output to a file.

The program involved is displaying lots of moving progress bars and the like. So the output file contains special characters such as `\r` to overwrite lines in those bars. When I `cat` the file, the progress bars get rerendered, which can take a lot of time over ssh.

How to create a text file that saves only the final states of progress bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the output through `col -b`, like:

```
col -b < rawoutput.txt > simplifiedversion.txt
```

[`man col`](https://manpages.debian.org/bsdmainutils/col.1):

> col —
>   filter reverse line feeds from input
>
> [...]
>
> [-b](https://manpages.debian.org/bsdmainutils/col.1#b) Do not output any backspaces, **printing only the last character written to each column position**.

The result will probably be corrupted if things like ANSI escape codes are used in the original file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the character `\r` is the only one and that your lines are formed as follows

```
X\rXX\rXXX\rXXXX\rXXXXX
```

you can use sed to get rid of everything before the last `\r`

```
$ echo $'X\rXX\rXXX\rXXXX\rXXXXX' >myfile
$ sed 's/^.*\r//' myfile
XXXXX
$
```